# Drupal 6 - execute code after taxonomy term delete

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-taxonomy

As the title says, how can I execute code after a taxonomy term is deleted. Drupal 7 has a hook_taxonomy_term_delete, but this function is not available for 6. Does anyone know a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corresponding hook in D6 is just called [`hook_taxonomy`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_taxonomy/6).

It is called thusly: `hook_taxonomy($op, $type, $array = NULL)` where:

- `$op` is one of `'delete'`, `'insert'`, `'update'`
- `$type` is one of `'vocabulary'`, `'term'`,
- and `$array` is the thing that `$op` is being done to.

So in your case an example implementation of that hook would go like this:

```
function example_taxonomy($op, $type, $array = NULL) {
    if ('term' == $type && 'delete' == $op) {
        // Execute the code here
    }
}
```